# my third monitor is disconnected when I re-plug the pc to dock

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a docked station for my laptop and connects two screens on it, at work, as well at home.

At work, all works perfectly, but at home, I have one of the monitors that I need systematically to reconnect, because it is systematically disconnected.

Normally, my screen configuration is the following

[image]

however, the second monitor is systematically disconnected when I unplug the pc, so I need to reconnect it each time I replug it...

I put it the main screen, however this didn't help to the problem.

Comment: Check/replace the cables. If the cable is bad or too long the signal transmission can stop.

Comment: usually I reconnect it via the display settings and it works without I should touch something physically.